# Can you use NSSortDescriptor to sort by a value not being null?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I have the following sort descriptors that sort an array of my business objects, ready to be displayed in a table, I'm starting off with some sample sorting code from a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"awardedOn" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil];
NSArray *sortedArray = [returnable sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

The objects that I'm displaying all will have a title. Only some of them will have an "awardedOn" set, which is an NSDate.

What I want to do:

1. Sort entire array so all the objects with an "awardedOn" set are
   displayed at the top
2. Within the two "sets", order them alphabetically
3. I don't care about the actual value of the date, I'm more interested
   if it exists or not

Something like this (Titles, the bold ones have a value for awardedOn)

- **Awesome**
- **Better**
- **Cool**
- Another
- Another One
- One more
- Yet Another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that using two descriptors like you first said, first by awardedOn, then by title. However, you need to provide a custom NSSortDescriptor for the awardedOn sort that looks someting like this:

```
#define NULL_OBJECT(a) ((a) == nil || [(a) isEqual:[NSNull null]]) 
@interface AwardedOnSortDescriptor : NSSortDescriptor {} 
@end 
@implementation AwardedOnSortDescriptor 
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone 
{ 
    return [[[self class] alloc] initWithKey:[self key] ascending:[self ascending] selector:[self selector]]; 
} 
- (NSComparisonResult)compareObject:(id)object1 toObject:(id)object2 
{ 
    if (NULL_OBJECT([object1 valueForKeyPath:[self key]])) { 
        if (NULL_OBJECT([object2 valueForKeyPath:[self key]]))  
            return NSOrderedSame; // If both objects have no awardedOn field, they are in the same "set"
        return NSOrderedDescending; // If the first one has no awardedOn, it is sorted after         
    } 
    if (NULL_OBJECT([object2 valueForKeyPath:[self key]])) { 
        return NSOrderedAscending; // If the second one has no awardedOn, it is sorted after
    } 
    return NSOrderedSame; // If they both have an awardedOn field, they are in the same "set"
} 
@end
```

This will allow you to have to separate sets: Awesome/Better/Cool and Another/Another One/One More/Yet another, in your example. After that, you should be good with:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[AwardedOnSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"awardedOn" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
```

On a final note, you might need a litte more work depending on what your "empty" awardedOn fields look like (I assumed, in the code above, that the field was set to null). You can take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145789

Comment: I've written a class based on this answer in Swift.
https://gist.github.com/evgeniyd/d974121b94b17931480c

Comment: This is awesome Eugene! Thanks :)
I also suggest you add another one for having the null objects at the top when ascending is true.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways:

1. When creating a business object, assign `awardedOn` date as `distantPast` if it does not exist and then do normal sorting by `awardedOn` and then by `title`.
2. Create sort descriptor with custom comparison method that will be called on each of business objects:

.

```
NSSortDescriptor *awardDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor descriptorWithKey:@"awardedOn"
                                                              ascending:NO 
                                                               selector:@selector(compareAwardedOn:)];

// In class for business object
- (NSComparisonResult)compareAwardedOn:(id)otherBusiness {
    // return custom NSComparison result after 
    // checking whether either of awardedOn dates are nil.
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Comment: How does this take into account the sorting on titles too?

Comment: Different attribute uses different sort descriptor. You pass an array of descriptors to an array of business objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use comparator:

```
_finalArray =  [_array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) 
               {
                   if([[obj1 valueForKey@"awardedOn"] lenght] && ![[obj2 valueForKey@"awardedOn"] lenght])
                       return NSOrderedDescending;
                    if([[obj2 valueForKey@"awardedOn"] lenght] && ![[obj1 valueForKey@"awardedOn"] lenght])
                       return NSOrderedAscending;
                   return NSOrderedSame;
               }];
```

Comment: that doesn't take into account the `title`

Comment: Every `lenght` should be `length` and There will be a colon `:` after every  `valueForKey` as `valueForKey:@"awardedOn"`